# CSS: Image is stretched to square, how to crop it?

Tags: python, html, css, image, crop

I have a for loop in Flask (Python) that creates a div for every post, that includes an image. I want it to be a square.
This is how it is written now:

```
  <div class="row">
  {% for post in posts.items %}
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
      {% if post.image %}
        <h4 class="col-centered"><a href="{{ url_for('article', slug=post.slug) }}" class="link">
          <img src="{{ post.imgsrc }}" height="370px" width="370px" class="img-rounded">
        </h4>
      {% endif %}
      <h3>
        <h4><a href="{{ url_for('article', slug=post.slug) }}">{{     post.title }}</a></h4>
      </h3>
  </div>
```

The problem is: this stretches the image into a box. How can I make it crop the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this-

Add a custom class (*cropImg*) and remove `height` and `width` on the img.

```css
.cropImg{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.cropImg h4 img{
  width:auto;
  max-width:auto
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  {% for post in posts.items %}
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 cropImg">
      {% if post.image %}
        <h4 class="col-centered"><a href="{{ url_for('article', slug=post.slug) }}" class="link">
          <img src="{{ post.imgsrc }}" height="" width="" class="img-rounded">
        </h4>
      {% endif %}
      <h3>
        <h4><a href="{{ url_for('article', slug=post.slug) }}">{{post.title }}</a></h4>
      </h3>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object-fit` property as the following:

CSS

```
img {
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

But it's not supported in IE. Check the support on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)

If you want another solution, you can wrap the image inside a div and remove the width and height attributes from the HTML.

CSS

```
.img-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```